# Delete all the matching lines except the first occurence of the Pattern

Tags: linux, shell

I have the below lines

logs/backups
logs/backups/config_bk

logs/backups/cofig_bkp
other/lines
and/some/more/lines

I have to search for a string "logs/backups" and need to delete all the lines which is having 
logs/backups except the first occurence... 
output which i need:

logs/backups

other/lines

and/some/more/lines

Comment: Does it need to be the first occurence or just the occurence without any subpaths?

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to preserve `logs/backups`, but not `logs/backups/*`, the solution is quite simple:

```
egrep  -v '^logs/backups.' <filename>
```

This will filter out (-v) any line that starts (represented by a caret) with 'logs/backups' and has at least one more chracter (represented by a dot).

Comment: @Newbee Great that I could be of help. As you are new to the site please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers